# Shortcut key for opening previous image in a folder

Tags: imagej

If we want to open next image in a folder in imagej then we use `ctrl+shift+o` but what shortcut key we can use to go backward.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl/command</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the previous image.

For those curious: I discovered this by [examining the source code](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/8e283502055d25b9f0456f4aad95afa30a649d45/src/main/java/ij/plugin/NextImageOpener.java#L5-L6). To find the source file in question, I typed "Open Next" into the search bar and clicked the Source button to open it in a web browser.

Comment: Thnx. But it goe's just 1 previous image, then it again goes to next images. I want to back in series of images.

Comment: It seems to work if you re-press the modifier keys before each press of O. I would classify that limitation as a bug; feel free to report a bug on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) or [on GitHub](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/issues/new).

Comment: Thnx. Are you sure i have to report it as bug